# dataclasses.asdict() not working as expected

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm using `dataclass` and `asdict` from [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), and I find that `asdict` doesn't work as I would expect when I introduce inheritance.

I use `dataclasses` to help me create dictionaries from classes so I can pass them into `django.shortcuts.render`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import asdict

@dataclass
class Base:
    name: str

class Test(Base):
    def __init__(self, age, *args, **kwargs):
        self.age = age
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

test = Test(age=20, name="john doe")

print(asdict(test))
```

I would expect the output to be

```py
{"age": 20, "name": "john doe"}
```

But what I get is only the keyword-value from the base-class

```py
{"name": "john doe"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct implementation for inheritance of a `dataclass` is covered [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance):

```
@dataclass
class Base:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Child(Base):
    age: int
```

Without this, the `__dataclass_fields__` attribute in the child class, which `asdict` uses to determine what should be in the dictionary, doesn't know about all of the fields you care about; it only has the inherited version:

```
>>> Test.__dataclass_fields__
{'name': Field(...)}
>>> Test.__dataclass_fields__ is Base.__dataclass_fields__
True
>>> Child.__dataclass_fields__
{'name': Field(...), 'age': Field(...)}
>>> Child.__dataclass_fields__ is Base.__dataclass_fields__
False
```

Also note you can simplify the imports to:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
```

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I had a silly error in that my child class attribute was missing the type annotation. It was a silly error but easy to miss at a glance.

Comment: @JasonCapriotti people are unlikely to spot that in a comment, I'd suggest writing another answer that shows what your problem was and how to solve it